# Is that correct to use two find functions in one get method

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

It work but I don't know is that correct solution to use Story.find two times in one get method? I use it only for stories.length.

```
router.get("/", (req, res) => {
let pagin = req.query.skiper;
let limiter = 5;
let skippy = (parseInt(pagin)) * limiter;
let stl, quan, tabl = [],
    ak = 0,
    next,
    back;
Story.find()
    .then(stories => {
        stl = Math.ceil(stories.length / limiter);
      ...
            back = parseInt(pagin) - 1;
        }
    });



Story.find()
    .limit(5)
    .skip(skippy)
    .populate("category")
    .then(stories => {
        res.render("stories", {
            stories: stories,
            tabl,
            next,
            back
        });
    });
```

});

When I try put first .then() like

```
Story.find()
.then(stories =>{...
    )
    .limit(5)
    .populate("category")
    .then(stories => {
        res.render("stories", {
            stories: stories,
            tabl,
            next,
            back
        });
    });
```

I am getting this error:
Story.find(...).then(...).limit is not a function

Comment: can You tell is first solution bad or it's correct?

Answer (score 0):

first solution seems very bad if you have to perform more than one task on one query why you dont use mongodb aggregation
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/ 
learn this and enjoy it!!!
Error you are facing is because  then is the callback function